# How to have two instances of Jboss 5 running on the same machine?

Tags: xml, spring, jboss

I'm a little stuck since I want to have two instances of Jboss running on my machine, when I first raise the problem without any problems, it is important to note that I already configure my environment variable as well as my properties-service so that it points to my ip and port.

Now I have tried to raise a second instance on my machine, already configure my environment variable assigning a different port to the first one, so also my properties-service.xml and my server.xml

In my first instance in the properties-service.xml:

```
system.com.host=192.168.2.15
        system.com.port=8480
```

In bindings-jboss-beans.xml

```
<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">Port</property>
               <property name="port">1099</property>
               <property name="description">The listening socket for the Naming service</property>
            </bean>

<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">RmiPort</property>
               <property name="port">1098</property>
               <property name="description">Socket Naming service uses to receive RMI requests from client proxies</property>
            </bean>
```

In my server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8543" />
```

Now in my second instance I have it as follows:

Properties-service-xml:

```
system.com.host=192.168.2.15
            system.com.port=8383
```

In the bindings-jboss-beans.xml:

```
<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">Port</property>
               <property name="port">1199</property>
               <property name="description">The listening socket for the Naming service</property>
            </bean>

            <bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">RmiPort</property>
               <property name="port">1195</property>
               <property name="description">Socket Naming service uses to receive RMI requests from client proxies</property>
            </bean>
```

In my server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8383" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8543" />
```

But when I want to raise my instance I get the following error:

```
[arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager_14] - Failed to create server socket on address 192.168.2.15 and port: 5,013
        [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=TransactionManager state=Configured
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.FatalError: [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager_9] - Could not get unique port.
```

Does anybody know what is it due to?

THANKS!

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigurePorts

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 5 has [Service Binding Manager](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ServiceBindingManager) that provide a centralized location where settings for all services that need to bind to ports can be configured.

You can start JBoss with the parameter `jboss.service.binding.set` set to either `ports-default`, `ports-01`, etc.

Eg:

```
run -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
```

The `jboss.service.binding.set` system property tells the ServiceBindingManager what set of ports to use.

To doing changes by hand check [JBoss AS ConfigurePorts](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigurePorts)

Ref: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AS5ServiceBindingManager